# how to make swf player with flex builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I make **Sampal.swf with adobe flash.** It has some **external links to load some swf files into this main Sampal.swf.** Now I want to run this main swf with **flex builder** application. I used **mx:SWFLoader** to that. This is code I had given...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                    xmlns:ns1="*"
                    applicationComplete="init()" name="Content" showStatusBar="false">

<mx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[

    private function init():void
    {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    }

    ]]>

    </mx:Script>
<mx:SWFLoader x="6" width="770" height="336" source="E:\Office\Sampal.swf"/>

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

When I run the application Main swf work properly. But that external links not works. If I click that kind of link, It gives this Error message. 
      **Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: file:///Flash/IRI02-I-07-I.swf**

Please give me some solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html):

```
The value of the source property represents a relative or absolute URL; 
  a ByteArray representing a SWF, GIF, JPEG, or PNG;  
  an object that implements IFlexDisplayObject; 
  a class whose type implements IFlexDisplayObject; 
  or a String that represents a class.
```

It appears that you have specified a disk path. Change this to a URL, or use another method to put the data in a format that SWFLoader can use.

Comment: I found the solution...
this is the code...

**<mx:SWFLoader id="loader" width="900" height="550" source="E:/Office/Sampal.swf" includeInLayout="true"/>**